# AspectJ and CDI

Tags: java, maven, cdi, aspectj

I'm trying to figure out a way to inject a bean into an aspect.

I mean

```
public class Greeter {
    public String greet(String name) {....}
}

...

public aspect GreeterAspect {
    @Inject
    private Greeter greeter

    ...
}
```

Executing that as a JUnit test with Arquillian + Wildfly 8.2.1 (managed and remote) I get these lines of log:

```
WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from x.y.z.Greeter because of underlying class loading error: Type org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.
WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from x.y.z.GreeterAspect because of underlying class loading error: Type org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.
```

and soon after I get the error

```
WELD-001474: Class x.y.z.Greeter is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader].
```

If I get it right, it complains that aspectjrt.jar is not in the classpath, though I've checked and I got it in the dependencies (using Maven to build). Was in `provided` scope, tried to switch to `compile` but nothing changed.

Can anyone help me solve the issue?

**EDIT: Solved the initial problm, now NullPointerException**

Solved the initial issue by adding the `aspectjrt.jar` to Arquillian deployment as suggested by simas_ch.

Though, when executing, I receive a `NullPointerException`

```
public class Greeter {
    public String greet(String name) {....}
}

...

public aspect GreeterAspect {
    @Inject
    private Greeter greeter;

    private pointcut pc() : execution(* x.y.z.SomeClass.someMethod(..));

    String around() : pc() {
        log.debug("Aspect is about to say something...");
        String result = greeter.greet("Stefano");
        log.debug("Aspect said: " + result);
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

I can see the first log line (`Aspect is about to say something...`) and then I get the `NullPointerException`, clearly the `Greeter` bean has not been injected.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it possible at all to inject beans into aspects?

Comment: `provided` scope means it is supplied by someone else, e.g. the framework. Did you check that is the case? Or did you tried without a special scope, e.g. adding it to the runtime classpath?

Comment: @Thomas yes, in fact I tried to move it to `compile`, but didn't change the situation. Do you mean add the jar to Wildfly classpath, or Arquillian's?

Comment: do you use Shrinkwrap? If yes you must add the dependencies:
File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")               .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

Comment: AFAIK `compile` is similar to `provided` in that it doesn't get added to the application. If try adding it to the ear's lib folder (by not providing any scope). Alternatively create a module for AspectJ (maybe there's already an existing one) and define a dependency on that module for your application (In JBoss 7 this would be in either MANIFEST.MF or jboss-deployment-structure.xml, not sure if the renamed it in Wildfly).

Comment: @Thomas you are wrong:

compile: This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

Comment: @simas_ch you definitely pointed me in the right way: add to explicitly add the `aspectjrt.jar` lib with ShrinkWrap to the deployment. Makes sense, after all Arquillian deals with micro deployments. Now, though, I got  second problem, a `NullPointerException` when the injected bean is called. Checked a bit, but it is not injected, it's `NULL`. Going to update the question.

Comment: Just wondering why you're even using aspectj when CDI has AOP concepts built in?

Comment: I don't think that you can use @Inject in a aspect. This is not a Java class the AspectJ weaver injects the aspect in your java classes according to the point cut.

Comment: @JohnAment I'm migrating a library (originally written for Spring) to JEE7 for deploy in an application server. There are several aspects in this library for a range of purposes that would be long to enumerate here. Some of them had `@Autowired` members, and I used `aspectOf` method to build these aspects, thus leveraging Spring dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the community, I managed to come out with a solution for both the problems. Leaving track here.

**PART ONE - aspectjrt.jar in deployment**

First, added `Shrinkwrap` to my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
       <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

`<version>` is not needed: Arquillian's `BOM` - already included - will take care of that.

Then add `aspectj` to deployment classpath:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianTest {
    private static final String[] DEPENDENCIES = {
        "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.7"
    };

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createEnvironement() {
        JavaArchive lib = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "libs.jar");
        for (String dependency : DEPENDENCIES) {
            lib.merge(Maven.resolver().resolve(dependency).withTransitivity().asSingle(JavaArchive.class));
        }

        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            // create you deployment here
            .as(JavaArchive.class);

        JavaArchive toBeDeployed = jar.merge(lib);

        return toBeDeployed;
    }

    // other stuff, like tests

}
```

**PART TWO: Injecting a bean into an aspect**

After further inquiries I think simas_ch was correct in saying that CDI does not inject beans into aspects.

Came out with a workaround: adding an `@Inject`ed member into a bean via the aspect.

```
public interface Advised {
    String buildGreeting(String name);
}

public class AdvisedImpl implements Advised {
    String buildGreeting(String name) {
        return "ADVISED";
    }
}

public class Greeter {
    public String greet(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + ".";
    }
}

...

public aspect GreeterAspect {
    @Inject
    private Greeter Advised.greeter; // adding the member to the interface / class. No need for getters / setters

    private pointcut pc() : execution(* x.y.z.Advised.buildGreeting(String));

    String around(Advised adv, String name) : pc() && target(adv) && args(name) {
        log.debug("Aspect is about to say something...");
        String result = proceed(adv, name) + " - " + adv.greeter.greet(name);
        log.debug("Aspect said: '" + result + "'");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Given the test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertThat(advised, not(is(nullValue())));
    assertThat(advised.buildGreeting("Stefano"), equalToIgnoringCase("advised - hello, stefano."));
}
```

it succeeds.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I wonder however if the structural change of the target CDI bean could have any unwanted side-effects.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos not that I ran into so far (and I've been coding a lot on this project, recently). Though, I do not use AspectJ in runtime, but in compile time (for performance sake), so that aspects are woven once and for all into the byte code (roughly said, I know). CDI works later, during execution, so I don't expect any clash between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with CDI, but if it's not picking up the aspect as a candidate for dependency injection, you should set it manually, preferably as soon as the aspect's dependencies are ready. You can gain access to an aspect (singleton by default), with `AspectName.aspectOf()`.

Maybe a startup singleton bean similar to this one:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class GreeterAspectSetup {

    @Inject
    private Greeter greeter;

    @PostConstruct
    private void setupGreeterAspect() {
        GreeterAspect.aspectOf().setGreeter(greeter);
    }

}
```

Of course, you would have to add the setter for the Greeter to the aspect, or  change the field's visibility in the aspect and set it directly.

Comment: I'm not much familiar with CDI either. I used the `aspectOf` method you mentioned as the factory method for these aspects in Spring contexts (thus leveraging Spring dependency injection). Do you know if there is a way to instruct CDI to use a different factory method rather than the default conctructor? This would solve the problem.

Comment: AFAI understand you, you need a [@Producer method](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_producer_method).

Comment: @G.Demecki tried, but the `@Producer` methods needs to be inside a managed bean (for what I understand, the same bean in which the produced bean is going to be ijected into). If inside the aspect, the method isn't called.

Comment: `@Produces` can be declared inside *any* managed bean... Spec says `A producer method must be a (...) method of a managed bean class or session bean class`. Anyway, I'm glad you solved your issue.

Comment: @G.Demecki yes, you are correct. Had a quick test on producers and I definitely got it wrong. But unfortunately the producer for the aspect isn't invoked, I guess because, for CDI, an aspect is not a bean.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but `@Producer` in this case would be useful if you would like to inject the aspect itself into some other piece of code, and it would be used on some other class than the aspect class itself to return the aspect.

Comment: But if it makes the returned aspect instance managed and by that a candidate for dependency injection post-processing, then I guess it's also a good method to make it work.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete It would be a much cleaner solution than mine, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a managed bean out of the aspect. Actually, it doesn't even seem to be invoked.

Comment: What about my solution? Did you try it out? Does it work?