# How to inject beans with AspectJ and CDI

Tags: cdi, aspectj

I've coded this aspect:

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingCacheAspect {
    @Pointcut("call * javax.cache.integration.CacheLoader.load(*)")
    void cacheLoadCalls() {};

    @Before("cacheLoadCalls")
    public void beforeCacheCalls() {}
}
```

Also, I'm using CDI, and I'm looking forward to figure out how to inject a bean into this aspect.

I guess that adding `@Inject` annotation will not be enought.

1. Is it possible?
2. How could I get it?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038652/aspectj-and-cdi) can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an interceptor instead of the aspect
Here is an example:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CacheLog{
}

@Interceptor
@CacheLog
public class CacheLogInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private YourBean yourBean;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object cacheLogMethodCall(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        //@Before

        yourBean.method();
        ...
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}


@CacheLog
public void cacheLoadCalls() {
 ...
 ...
}
```